# What is the razor in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am new to ASP.NET and MVC. I have quick question. Please explain the concept of 'Razor' in ASP.NET.

Specifically, what is the meaning of the following code?

```
<ul>
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
<li>@i</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Here's the documentation for Razor: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)

Comment: Do you know the idea of loops?

Answer (score 3):

Razor enables you to start with static HTML and then make it dynamic by adding server code to it. In other words, you can use C# alongside HTML to create a dynamic web page.

In this example, you have a for loop, and it creates an `<li>` element on each iteration. This is better than having to type out the full `<ul>` in static HTML for many reasons. Some reasons include:

- Easier to maintain and update
- Faster to develop
- You have the ability to perform complex (or preferably not-so-complex) calculations that can be inserted alongside static HTML

That code will output:

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Rendered HTML

- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

You can read more about what the Razor View Engine is here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: i want some details regarding rezor

Comment: @user2820365: What details are you looking for?  Razor is just a syntax used to include server-side code in a View.  That's all.

Comment: @user2820365 I have tried to explain a little about what razor is, and why it is helpful in the example you provided.

Comment: @user2820365 No problem. Please select an answer if you feel your question has been answered. For future reference, you should put more research effort into your questions, as this one contained very little.

Comment: I feel it is worth noting that within the MVC pattern, views (where Razor comes in) should be pretty dumb.  Performing complex (or preferably not-so-complex) calculations that can be inserted alongside static HTML, is a strength of the Razor engine.  However, consider taking care of these complex calculations in another, more appropriate layer (if possible, of course)

Comment: I agree with you @Neil.Allen and hesitated on that line. I basically just wanted to say that you have the ability to insert C# next to HTML, but didn't know a good way to phrase it. I don't want to encourage poor separation of concerns, but it is, as you said, a capability (strength) of Razor.

Answer (score 1):

Razor is new view engine for ASP.NET where you can start of a code block with @ character.
Unlike <% %> code, you dont need to close the blocks.

I googled it and these are the top results.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_razor.asp

Comment: please give some information

Comment: @user2820365 : there are plenty of ressources online about this... your question clearly shows a lack of research !

Comment: Like, you can type String time = "The time is" + @DateTime.Now and it will display The time is 9/26/2013 17:37:08 PM

Comment: Note that the only reason you sometimes don't have to close the razor blocks is because it is unambiguous. Think of it how sometimes you do not have to add `{` and `}` for `if`/`for`/etc statements when there is only one line. For multiline Razor code (see OP's example), you do need a beginning and ending (`@{` and `}`).